Wittgenstein, 4.063

An illustration to explain the concept of truth. A black spot on white paper; the form of the spot can be described by saying of each point of the plane whether it is white or black. To the fact that a point is black corresponds a positive fact; to the fact that a point is white (not black), a negative fact. If I indicate a point of the plane (a truth-value in Frege’s terminology), this corresponds to the assumption proposed for judgment, etc. etc.
But to be able to say that a point is black or white, I must first know under what conditions a point is called white or black; in order to be able to say “p” is true (or false) I must have determined under what conditions I call “p” true, and thereby I determine the sense of the proposition.
The point at which the simile breaks down is this: we can indicate a point on the paper, without knowing what white and black are; but to a proposition without a sense corresponds nothing at all, for it signifies no thing (truth-value) whose properties are called “false” or “true”; the verb of the proposition is not “is true” or “is false”—as Frege thought—but that which “is true” must already contain the verb.

Wittgenstein, TLP, 4.063
Why is it so hard to read? Is it intentionally overcomplicated? Did I understand this paragraph right?
My understanding and questions which I have (I'm stating this by points, please criticize by points too):

The possibility of a spot to be whether black or white is the form of a spot. And it illustrates that the form of the proposition assumes that it may be either true or false.

We decide whether proposition is true by comparing this with an actual state of things. (What's the difference with Frege's opinion then?)

When Wittgenstein talks about "breaking of the simile", what does he mean? Is he talking about simile between the analogy and his claim? Or he's talking about the simile between his opinion and that of Frege?

In what exactly "breaking of the simile" consists?



the verb of the proposition is not “is true” or “is false”—as Frege thought—but that which “is true” must already contain the verb.



Does this syntax seem natural for a native speaker?



The possibility of a spot to be whether black or white is the form of a spot. And it illustrates that the form of the proposition assumes that it may be either true or false.


Yes, that is indeed the starting point of the analogy, a proposition by definition is either true or false, so in that sense it is similar to a spot on the paper that can be either black or white (not black).  --  I just wouldn't say "the possibility", it's the very "shape" of it in terms of what the discourse can be about it: anyway, this might just be a matter of exposition.


We decide whether proposition is true by comparing this with an actual state of things. (What's the difference with Frege's opinion then?)


None up to that point.


When Wittgenstein talks about "breaking of the simile", what does he mean? Is he talking about simile between the analogy and his claim? Or he's talking about the simile between his opinion and that of Frege?


Aren't those two the same?  The analogy breaks between "spots on the paper" and "propositions on the plane of truth".


In what exactly "breaking of the simile" consists?


It is "easy", almost innate, to see whether a spot is on the paper, the same is not for recognizing propositions: the point, as I understand it, is that to go from an utterance or piece of text to a proposition we need to preliminarily understand not only the utterance or piece of text and what it means, but also under which conditions (in which "form") it may or may not be true.
In more modern and more technical terms, that becomes the distinction between classical and non-classical logic, specifically the fact that in classical logic all propositions are by assumption decidable: which in turn means assume that, for any proposition P, either "P is true" or "~P is true" is given.  And Fregean of course is the prototype of classical.


<<the verb of the proposition is not "is true" or "is false" - as Frege thought - but that which "is true" must already contain the verb.>>  Does this syntax seem natural for a native speaker?


It's not colloquial English, but other than that I don't find it particularly unnatural, though I am not an English native speaker myself.  But keep in mind the original is not in English, that is a translation... where W. is belabouring the point that, while a "spot on the page" is intrinsically either black or not black, "Socrates is mortal" does not intrinsically mean "'Socrates is mortal' is true": in other words, talk about Socrates is not talk about talk about Socrates.
